# Cannot redeclare get_default_keyword() (previously declared in /wp-content/mu-plugins/config.php:130) in /mu-plugins/p3-profiler.php on line 122

Tags: wordpress

Already have overwrote a fresh install of WordPress with the server files, minus config.php but no luck.

Error from nginx logs:

```
Cannot redeclare get_default_keyword() (previously declared in /var/www/mydomain.net/htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins/config.php:130) in /var/www/mydomain.net/htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins/p3-profiler.php on line 122
```